# Did dinosaurs exist?

Tags: fossil-record, paleontology

I find it hard to believe that dinosaurs ever existed. They were never mentioned and totally skipped in the holy books (Old Testament, New Testament, Qur'an) although these books do contain stories as old as it gets (to Adam and Eve, Noah, The Great Flood, and Ibrahim). How can we know dinosaurs existed?

Comment: What about the behemoth? The wikipedia article mentions "Behemoth is commonly identified as possibly being a sauropod dinosaur" See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behemoth

Comment: I know of nobody who claims that dinosaurs did not exist. Please find a notable example of this claim in order to make this an appropriate question.

Comment: @DJClayworth the claim is "dinosaurs existed" and the OP is skeptical of that. See [If a claim is commonly accepted, does questioning it require a notable counter-claim?](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1406/if-a-claim-is-commonly-accepted-does-questioning-it-require-a-notable-counter-c)

Comment: If I'd seen that question I'd have voted against it. It opens up the door to questions like  "Is there really a country called Spain?"; "Did Richard Nixon exist?"; "Is Obama a Christian?".

Comment: @Believer: If you believe the scientific evidence for dinosaurs, then presumably you don't believe the *literal* truth for the contradicting stories of Adam and Eve and the Great Flood. So, it is odd to see them being offered as evidence as "old stories". Also, dinosaurs were around long before the "as old as it gets" biblical stories.

Comment: @Oddthinking maybe Believer is just unfamiliar with the scientific evidence of the existence of dinosaurs, or that there is physical evidence, that we do have fossils and soft tissues of dinosaurs.

Comment: @SamIAm: Indubitably. I'm waiting for someone with a better grasp of that evidence answers before I try. I'm just trying to clumsily explain that Believer's counter-evidence has a bit of a mismatch with the theory, leading to non-sequiturs.

Comment: @Oddthnking I'd like to see Believer reply here in comments.  The problem with discussing religion is not literalists but non-literalists.  If you allow me to believe in only something **like** Genesis then I can pick and choose a buffet of beliefs that approaches self-consistency. But such a person could still espouse that if its not mentioned in the Bible, maybe it did not really exist...

Comment: Science, typically.

Comment: Dinosaurs only existed in Australia. The bible doesn't mention marsupials or monotremes either. Joking aside, do you regard the fossil record as bogus?

Comment: My only problem is of course religious books otherwise I have no problem believing. Either one of them is true, dinosaurs or religion not both. BTW I have seen fossils myself, have done extensive search on dinosaurs, been to dinosaurs museum. Even step on their foot print left 70 million years ago.

Comment: @Believer Your views are in the minority (to the point of being unique), even among ardent adherents to the literal truth of religious texts. See http://www.creationscience.com/onlinebook/FAQ25.html#wp1614541

Comment: Believer's comments above indicate to me that he does in fact personally believe in dinosaurs. So that makes this a non-question.

Comment: I want to believe in it but I have a hard time.

Comment: If you've seen dinosaur fossils, stepped on their footprints, yet still have a hard time believing, then I don't see what evidence could possibly persuade you. What are you expecting us to say?

Comment: I am thinking something like an answer to "Is the earth 6000 years old?" or something that is just really convincing

Comment: The existence of thousands of dinosaur skeletons is incredibly convincing. What evidence could you imagine that would be more convincing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a whole [science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_paleontology) dedicated to the study of [fossils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil), which we know puzzled mankind at least since 500bc:

> In ancient times Xenophanes (570-480 BC) wrote about fossil sea shells indicating that land was once under water

[Dinosaurs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaur) is a very broad term and refers to a group of animals of which we have bones and entire skeletons.

> Dinosaurs are a diverse group of animals of the clade Dinosauria. They first appeared during the Triassic period, approximately 230 million years ago, and became the dominant terrestrial vertebrates for 135 million years, from the beginning of the Jurassic (about 200 million years ago) until the end of the Cretaceous (65.5 million years ago), when the Cretaceous–Paleogene extinction event led to the extinction of most dinosaur groups at the close of the Mesozoic era. The fossil record indicates that birds evolved from theropod dinosaurs during the Jurassic, and consequently they are considered a type of dinosaur in modern classification systems.

[image: Oxford Dino]
<sup>I own copyright for the photo</sup>

You can visit most museums and see or touch some fossils them if that convinces you.

Comment: But Wikipedia is not a sufficiently reliable source to be solely used in meeting Skeptics Exchange standards for a well-referenced answer. Could you please add references that are not wikipedia? :-)

Comment: @Paul: I think the 154 references on that Wikipedia page are very sufficient.

Comment: Wikipedia is good enough for [high school level](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5/faq-must-all-answers-be-referenced) claims. These are all (I would defend) primary school* level... *According to my son who is in primary school and loves dinosaurs.

Comment: I still think one could argue that Dinosaurs are indeed mentioned in the holy books, nullifying the concern the Dinosaurs alleged absence causes the OP.  See http://www.clarifyingchristianity.com/dinos.shtml

Comment: I have touched dinosaurs footprint embedded in rock, have gone to museuem. I just have hard time believing it. For me it if I want to believe in it I must quit my religion.

Comment: @Believer Catholics have no problems with dinosaurs, big bang and evolution, and they are clearly Christians. One could say, they are The Real Christians™.

Comment: @Sklivvz for info I am Muslim. For me it is either Dinosaurs or Islam.

Comment: @Believer Ok, other [Muslims](http://www.turntoislam.com/forum/showthread.php?t=7584) don't really have a problem with that. Also, many Muslims of the past. Maybe you can speak with some different Muslim Imam about it?

Comment: @Believer: Can you find any mention of cats in the Koran or Bible?

Comment: @Henry, Dinosaurs is the equation changer. It invalidates everything Quran and bible says. Because they lived for millions of years. If that is true, the Islamic theory of evolution (derived form Christianity) falls flat and almost everything it says is then wrong. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Believer It seems to me that your question isn't really whether dinosaurs exist, but whether it is possible to reconcile the existence of dinosaurs with Islam. [The answer appears to be "yes", for most Muslims.](http://www.islamfortoday.com/emerick16.htm)

Comment: "I just have hard time believing it. For me it if I want to believe in it I must quit my religion." You are committing the "[appeal to consequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_consequences)" fallacy. Just because you don't like the consequences of a claim is not a reason to accept or reject it. You should base your decision on the preponderance of evidence.